# Cucumber @rerun generates multiple files

Tags: protractor, cucumber

When executing Cucumber with rerun formatter:

```
rerun:target/@rerun.txt
```

it's generating multiple files like:

```
@rerun.733988.txt
@rerun.987565.txt
...
```

any idea why it is happening?

Update:

**Issue** The Cucumber tests are executed in parallel, as result multiple files were generated.

**Solution** To write a post execution hook which will aggregate all files into single one.

Answer (score 0):

So the files were generated because the tests were running in parallel.

The solution was to create a function which will be called at the end of execution and will aggregate all result into single file.